# How to schedule specific test in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been looking for an answer to this question for a long time.

I have a big project with a lot of tests in jenkins.

I want that some of the tests run every time someone does "push".

and all the tests run every night.

How can I do this?

with the "Build periodically" I build all the tests with schedule and I dont found thet I can build specific tests.

Thank!

EDIT:
I run the tests with gradle, this is the configuratuin:
[image: Gradle build]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the BUILD_CAUSE variable

on nightly trigger **TIMERTRIGGER=true**  , after every push the value will be **SCMTRIGGER**

after that you can set a parameter and run the tests using it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mor Lajb! but, Could you elaborate? where i can use the BUILD_CAUSE variable? where i can set a parameter? whet is the plugin thet i use? i use with the Build periodically?

Comment: HI @ShiraOzeri

I will try give some more information : 

The env variable BUILD_CAUSE contain the following values : 
**SCMTRIGGER** when it trigger with scm change

**TIMERTRIGGER** on a timer trigger

**MANUALTRIGGER** on manual trigger

no need to install any plugin to have this environment variable.

you can access this parameter in bash step with **$BUILD_CAUSE**

BTW , how do you run the tests ? is in maven , gradle or some other step.

add more description of your flow , and I will try to help

Comment: Ok, so I edit my question. I use gradle and run from jenkins the tests. where I need to add the BUILD_CAUSE? I dont know this variable. and again- thanks for the help.